Is there a way of improving my solution by using Numpy vectorization?
I have the following exercise. Given a set of coordinates in a 3x4 matrix:
coord = np.array([
    [2,3],
    [0,1],
    [2,2],
    [2,3],
    [1,1],
    [2,3],
    [1,1]
])

Given a 3x4 matrix total initially set with all entries equal to 0, I want to sum all the amount in each cell by the following quantities:
amounts = np.array([0.5,1.1,0.2,0.9,1.3,0.4,2.0])

For example:
total[2,3] = 0.5 + 0.9 + 0.4 = 1.8.
I did the following code:
x = coord[:,0]
y = coord[:,1]

total = np.zeros((3,4))
for i in range(len(amounts)):
    total[x[i], y[i]] = total[x[i], y[i]] + amounts[i]

Can this be further improved by using Numpy vectorization or functions? Maybe in a way that can be particularly useful for larger datasets.

Please note that vectorization only help for large arrays, it will be slow anyway for small ones (what is slow is Numpy calls, not the loop itself). A solution is to use Cython (native compiler) or Numba (JIT) so to write a vectorized solution yourself. It should be significantly faster than np.add.at.
